# Jarník-Besicovitch and outer measure

Tags: diophantine-approximation, hausdorff-dimension

The set $A_\tau$ of irrational numbers $x$ which are $\tau$-approximable, i.e., that satisfy the estimate
$$\left|x - \frac{p}{q}\right| \leq \frac{1}{q^\tau}$$
for infinitely many rationals $p/q$, has Hausdorff dimension $2/\tau$. This is the so called Jarník-Besicovitch theorem. What can be said about the $2/\tau$-Hausdorff outer measure of $A_\tau$? Is it always positive or infinite? If one replaces $1/q^\tau$ with $C/q^\tau$ for some $C > 0$, how does it depend on $C$?

EDIT: Some remarks:

1) The set $A_\tau$ is 1-periodic in the sense that $A_\tau + 1 = A_\tau$. This means that the outer measure if positive is infinite and one has to consider instead $A_\tau \cap [0,1]$ to get something meaningful.

2) Using propositions 8.5, 8.6 and 10.4 from Falconer's book Fractal Geometry one deduces that the $2/\tau$-outer-measure of the set $\bigcap_{\tau' < \tau} A_{\tau'}$, which is in principle bigger than $A_\tau$, is strictly positive.

Comment: Did you try direct calculations?

Comment: No, but I assumed that maybe this was widely known. From what I could see from Besicovitch's original proof (I didn't read it in detail) they prove that the dimension is $\geq 2/\tau$ by checking that it cannot be contained in a set of dimension $2/\tau - \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. This in principle gives no information about the outer measure.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov what do you mean by direct calculation here?

Comment: I believe Jarnik proved much more precise results, so you may want to dig up his papers or look for commentaries on what he did. I posted one such "more precise" result in [this 25 March 2001 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=243561) (scroll down to where "Jarnik's theorem (simplified):" appears on the left side).

Comment: I mean that for a fixed $q$ we have $\varphi(q)$ covering intervals of total `measure' $\varphi(q)(\frac{2}{q^{\tau}})^{2/\tau}=\frac{\varphi(q)}{q^2}$. So we have to find something like $\sum_{Q_1<q<Q_2}\frac{\varphi(q)}{q^2}$ as $Q_1,Q_2\to\infty$.

Comment: A possibly useful survey paper is [*Hausdorff dimension and Diophantine approximation*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305399) by Maurice Dodson and Simon Kristensen (2003).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any interval $I$, the $2/\tau$-Hausdorff outer measure of the set $A_\tau \cap I$ is always infinite for $\tau \neq 2$ and equal to $|I|$ for $\tau = 2$, independently of the constant $C$. This is a consequence of Jarník's theorem, which can be consulted here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01948. Incidentally these notes were uploaded one month after my original question.